# Angularjs ngMessages not showing messages for non validation messages

Tags: angularjs, flash-message, ng-messages

I am attempting to use the ngMessages directive, to show two different messages for a rich text editor that auto saves... which are simply "Saved" and "Saving..."

I have exposed a variable on the controller which is returning a function which returns a property from the service behind the controller (as apparently this is the only way to get two way binding).

```
<div class="col-md-2" ng-messages="saveStatus" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="saving">Saving changes.....</div>
    <div ng-message="'saved'">SAVED!</div>
</div>
```

And my controller variable is very simply

```
$scope.saveStatus = function () {
     return reportService.status;
}
```

And my service simply puts a get accessor on a private variable

```
 get status() {
       return privateStatus;
 }
```

In my Chrome dev tools I can see that the saveStatus is in scope and returning a fucntion. Even if I don't use a function (so the message should always say "SAVED!") the message still does not appear....

The output seems to be formatted by ngMessages and so I think it is loaded and available, but I can't find ANY examples on the web of where they are not using the $errors collection!

```
<div class="col-md-2 ng-inactive" ng-messages="saveStatus" role="alert">
    <!-- ngMessage: saving -->
    <!-- ngMessage: saved -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

According to the documentation, it is possible to associate to  `ng-messages` directive a collection of key/value and `$error` is just an example of collection:

> The ngMessages directive listens on a key/value collection which is
>   set on the ngMessages attribute. Since the ngModel directive exposes
>   an $error object, this error object can be used with ngMessages to
>   display control error messages in an easier way than with just regular
>   angular template directives.

Try to update your service to return a collection object, for example to report a "saving" situation try to return {saving : true}. This worked for me.